# Get annotations of return type in Java

Tags: java, methods, annotations, return

I'm using Spring MVC and am using aspects to advise my controllers. I'm running into one issue: controllers that return a value annotated with the @ResponseBody type. How are you able to find the annotations applied to the return type?

```
@Around("myPointcut()")
private Object checkAnnotations(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
    Object result = pjp.proceed();
    Method method = ((MethodSignature)pjp.getSignature()).getMethod();
    System.out.println("Checking return type annotations.");
    for(Annotation annotation : method.getReturnType().getAnnotations()){
        System.out.println(annotation.toString());
    }
    System.out.println("Checking annotations on returned object.");
    for(Annotation annotation : result.getClass().getAnnotations()){
        System.out.println(annotation.toString());      
    }
    return result;
}
```

The method being advised:

```
@RequestMapping("/Test")
public @ResponseBody String doTest(){
    return "Test";
}
```

Unfortunately, neither of these methods seem to have the desired effect. I can retrieve annotations on the type of object being returned, but not the ones being added at return time.

Comment: It is method annotation not return object's annotation.

Comment: @amir-pashazadeh - It can be done either way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `@ResponseBody` annotation annotates a *method*, so i would imagine you would want to get the method annotations.

i'm not a spring expert, but the examples i saw looked like:

```
@RequestMapping("/Test")
@ResponseBody
public String doTest(){
    return "Test";
}
```

Comment: I've updated my original post with the simple method being advised. When I check annotations on the method, I can find the @ RequestMapping, but @ ResponseBody is nowhere to be found.

Comment: That gives me a decent workaround. I wasn't aware the annotation could be applied to the entire method, rather than just the return type (both appear to work exactly the same, at least as far as Spring is concerned). By annotating it this way, I can at least find the mapping. So thank you, since it gives me a way to accomplish what I want. I'd still be interested to know if there is a way to retrieve it when annotated as in my original post, though.

Comment: Annotations can't be applied to return values. Placing the annotation where it's placed in your question, or where it's placed in this answer, is strictly equivalent.

Comment: @Apropos - i don't see a way of getting that if it doesn't show up as one of the method's annotations.  it's not going to be on the return type class, since that could be anything.

Comment: @JB-Nizet - It's not strictly equivalent if I'm able to get the annotation when it's annotated one way and not when it's annotated the other.

Comment: @jtahlborn - It's certainly a bit vexing. I'm considering digging through the Spring source code and seeing if I can find how they access it.

Comment: The problem must be elsewhere. See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/4190246) for an example that works as expected.

Comment: @JB-Niznet : Well, I have no idea what the problem was. With your example, I decided to try it again, and while I swear I'm doing exactly the same thing that I was before (using method.getAnnotations() and just printing them out), it's now working exactly as you claimed it should. I can only conclude that I made some mistake earlier, even if I have no clue what it could have been. So thanks to both you and jtahlborn for your help.

Comment: @JBNizet java 8 adds type annotation, so is this statement still true (Annotations can't be applied to return values)?

Answer (score 1):

It is a type annotation. It is available since Java 8. This gives you a head start: http://java.dzone.com/articles/java-8-type-annotations